# How to get the instance(UIApplication) of the front most application from SpringBoard tweak in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-privateapi, cydia, tweak

I need get the `UIApplication` instance of the current front most app.I use `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` but get only the instance of `SpringBoard`, does any one know how can I do it?Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Different processes (apps) live in different memory spaces. You can't access classes from other running applications from within the SpringBoard application. You'll need to inject your code into the app that you are trying to interact with.